# inter procedural taint analysis

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, taint

The taint analyser provided by roslynsecurityguard(C#) supports only intra procedural taint analysis. Can any one suggest any other tool that can do inter procedural taint analysis for C#?
Thanks in advance!